# Jetty HTTP 2 Client

Tags: java, jetty, httpclient, http2

Tried to use Http 2 to connect to https://graph.facebook.com . It
supports Http2, I checked. Used Jetty Http Client. Configured it with adding alpn_boot location to -Xbootclasspath  on startup and using

```
mHttp2JettyClient = new HTTP2Client();
    mHttp2JettyClientWrapper =
        new HttpClient(new         HttpClientTransportOverHTTP2(mHttp2JettyClient), sslContextFactory);
...
mHttp2JettyClient.start();
mHttp2JettyClientWrapper.start();
...
jettyHttpRequest.version(HttpVersion.HTTP_2);
```

But keep getting Timeout. The same request from browser/Jetty with Http1 works.
And if I try to request directly

```
ContentResponse  = mHttp2JettyClientWrapper.GET(jettyRequest.getURI());
```

Then it just gets stuck and doesn't return.
Any ideas?

Comment: Anybody used Jetty Http client with Http2 and can share some code sample, perhaps? :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was non complete path to alpn-boot jar. Sorry :)

Comment: Glad you solved. Can you post the full code for reference to other people ?

Comment: It's not really code. Just add the full path to Xbootclasspath


    -Xbootclasspath/p:/Users/MYNAME/thirdparty/alpn_boot/alpn-boot-8.1.7.v20160121.jar